# Add User Control from another project SharePoint 2013 nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I created User Control and tested it in a page in the same project and everything worked fine. Then I created a Nuget Package and added it to the destination project. Everything seems to work - the type is defined and I can create the control. However, the child controls of my control are not initialized - all of them are `null`.  How can I repair that? I tried different takes on assembly register:

`<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="SomeNamespace" Assembly="MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx"%>`
This one works as I described.

This `<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" TagName="CustomControl" Src="../../../_controltemplates/15/Project/CustomControl.ascx" %>` returns parsing error (not finding code behind - it is compiled into dll).

I tried explicitly addind `.cs` files and removing `.ascx`. The only solution I came up with is manually in constructor initializing all of the child controls of my Custom Control. But it is the last resort. I would like to use built in mechanism for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found some kind of a solution. I just added both Register clauses

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="SomeNamespace" Assembly="MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" TagName="CustomControl" Src="../../../_controltemplates/15/Project/CustomControl.ascx" %>
```

and added in `.nuspec`:

```
<files>
    <file src="ControlTemplates\" target="content\ControlTemplates" />
    <file src="Layouts\" target="content\Layouts" />
</files>
```

after setting for `CustomControl.ascx.cs` property `Copy to Outputdirectory` to `Copy always`.

It isn't the solution I was looking for - there are warnings about multiple definitions of controls and I have to edit `.csproj` after every package update to add `<DependentUpon>` for files. And I have to remember to add some UserControl and Image mapped folder before first downloading the package, otherwise Visual Studio doesn't see the control. Nevertheless, it works.